# How to solve asynchronous in using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, asynchronous, firefox-addon

How can i modify the following code to run in a synchronous way ? The AddonManager is an asynchronous call and I could not able to get the proper result.

```
function initWithPrivs (java, ext_id, jarFiles) {

    var [loader, urls] = init(java, ext_id, jarFiles);
    policyAdd(loader, urls);
    return [loader, urls];
}

function init (java, ext_id, jarFiles) {

var classLoader;
var fURLs=[];
    JAVA = java;
    try {  

      Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");  
 AddonManager.getAddonByID("a@a.com",function(addon) {  

     //Some code to process fURLs and classLoader
     //If i put return here its shows me error 
}
);
  return [classLoader,fURLs];  //If i use return here it return null.
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't. It is asynchronous for a reason, disk access takes time. You can somewhat simplify asynchronous code using generators but it isn't worth the effort for simple cases.

Comment: This is asynchronous to speed up the loading of the page in the browser.  If your goal is "minimize loading speed" then making this synchronous seems like a good plan, otherwise, not so much.

Comment: This seems rather silly to force everything to be asynchronous.  The result is that you make repeated calls to this same overly-abstracted and bloated interface, to do tiny bits of the same task, over and over, instead of doing it ONE TIME, and using the SAME OBJECT thereafter.  I simply want to retrieve the entire addons object JUST ONCE to use in a dozen spots accessing different properties.  How is asynchronous helping anyone now in this use case?  The trivial time "saved", is wasted by redundant calls and memory leakage and bloated code which is an order of magnitude more complicated.

Comment: Instead of calling the method ONCE, I will have to call it A DOZEN TIMES OR MORE.  Computers are quite speedy nowadays.  It is irrational to be so obsessive neurotic and about code design that everyone is forced into async.  Async for network connections, absolutely.  But to retrieve one object which is in memory already (not a disk access), that is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't make this code sync, use the async method.

So, I do not recommend doing this, but I'll mention it anyhow, you could do something like:

```
var addonObj = null;
AddonManager.getAddonByID("a@a.com",function(addon) {
    addonObj = addon;
});
var thread = Cc["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"].getService().currentThread;
while (addonObj == null)
  thread.processNextEvent(true);
// addonObj is no longer null...
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to do:

```
  var addonObj = -1;
AddonManager.getAddonByID("a@a.com",function(addon) {
    addonObj = addon;
});
var thread = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"].getService().currentThread;
while (addonObj != null || addonObj == -1)
  thread.processNextEvent(true);
// addonObj is no longer null...
```

in case the Addon is not installed?

Comment: If I am using this from within my own addon, I can be reasonably certain that it is installed, so the other usage would probably suffice.  If not, then something else is horribly broken and I'd probably need to scrub the profile anyways to fix it.  If I am poking around everyone else's addons, and querying things which may or may not be installed, then this alternative would seem to prevent an infinite loop.